# RabbitMQ - deal with unreliable service

Tags: rabbitmq, polly, retry-logic, reliable-message-delivery, unreliable-connection

I have a service AAA that posts 10 to 50 thousand messages a minute to a RabbitMQ exchange. A .NET Core service BBB subscribes to a queue (to which all messages are routed) and for each message calls another HTTP service CCC over Internet. The problem is CCC is very unreliable, a few times a day it goes completely off for a minute or two and at least once a week it dies for an hour.

I don't have control over AAA or CCC. How can I use RabbitMQ routing features to reliably deliver all messages trought?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an unreliable third-party service CCC which goes offline for minutes or hours, a [circuit-breaker](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker) can be useful.  Configure the circuit-breaker to break when it detects CCC is offline.

You can monitor the circuit-breaker state to detect when CCC is offline and/or log changes of circuit-state for later analysis.

Polly's circuit-breaker allows you to [hook in any custom code on transitions of circuit state](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker#delegates-on-transitions-of-circuit-state--polly-v40), so you could also:

- when the circuit breaks, unsubscribe from the RabbitMQ queue.
- when the circuit half-opens, resubscribe to the RabbitMQ queue at narrow parallelism (say, with a pre-fetch count of only 1 or 2 ... only enough messages for the circuit-breaker to retry the circuit).
- when the circuit closes (healthy again), resubscribe to the RabbitMQ queue at full throughput.

This pattern would prevent you getting 100000s of messages flowing over to the RabbitMQ error/dead-letter/your custom retry queue, as soon as the circuit-breaker detects CCC is offline.

You would still need to consider what happens to the messages that do fail (before the circuit breaks or while retesting it), as described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120543/).  Direct them to an error/retry queue.  Or if the unsubscribe-when-CCC-is-down pattern works well enough with your real world parameters, you may be able to let messages which fail simply return to the original queue.

---

If CCC experiences also any *transient* faults (faulting for only a few seconds), consider introducing a [WaitAndRetry policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#wait-and-retry).

---

With incoming message rates potentially at 1000s per second, you likely want to consider how you are limiting *parallelism* of message processing within BBB and/or the timeout you set on calls to CCC.  Without this you may [risk memory bulges in the consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#acknowledgement-modes) as more and more messages arrive while other requests are hanging on a response from CCC before it times out; a high timeout on CCC clearly exacerbates this.  Consumer parallelism can be limited by using manual `ack` and applying a `pre-fetch count`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your subscription method in AAA is synchronous, throwing an exception will cause Rabbit to put the message into a dead letter queue.  From there you could move them back or manually inspect them.  Alternatively, you could re-publish it to the same exchange, but you might have an issue with messages that fail over and over filling up the queue.  To avoid that, publish it with a header that would prevent it from entering the original queue again.  Create another persistent queue that  uses your new header as a filter. Presto, you have a re-try queue.  You can subscribe to it for retries and/or alerts, use Shovel to move messages back to the original queue, whatever.